# For Loop Adding Extra Rows to The Data Frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, infinite-loop

Hello I am very new to the programming world and data science as well, and I am trying to work my way through it.

I am trying to assign values to the column in a data frame and using for loop such that the data frame is divided into ten groups and every row in every group is assigned a rank, such that row 1 to 10 is assigned as rank 1 and row 11 to 20 is assigned as rank 2 and so on. The original dimension of subset data set is 100 * 6

My data frame looks like
[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DtZ2.png)

The codes I have written are:

```
   x <- round(nrow(subset) / 10)
   a=1
   for(j in 1:10){
    for(i in a:x){
      subset[i, "rank"] = j
    }
    j = j + 1
    a = x + 1
    x = x * j
    }
```

However, the loop runs infinitely and keeps on adding additional rows to the data frame. I had to manually stop the loop and the resulting dimension of the subset data frame was 17926 * 6.

Please help me understand where am I going wrong in writing the loop.

P.S. subset is a data frame name and not the subset function in R

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Please [don't post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @De Novo, I am new here, but I think I have only posted the image of the data frame and not the code. I wrote the code in body of the post. How can I post the data frame?

Comment: To clarify, that's a general statement. Don't post images of your code or your data. Post code that recreates an example of your data frame.  One way to do this is to copy and paste the output of `dput(df)`, where `df` is your data frame. If it is very large, it is better to do this with a smaller example.

Comment: It seems to me it would be simpler to assign this without a loop, e.g. with `subset$rank <- rep(1:10, each = 10)`.

Comment: @JonSpring, The above suggestion works like magic, however it fails if the data frame has row count that is not a multiple of 10. I used this on my production data frame which has dimension of 24312 * 6 it failed with the following error :

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rank5, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 24310 rows, data has 24312.

Is there a way to get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better for you to start working with vectorized calculations instead of loops. This will help you in the future.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100)
df$rank <- (df$x-1)%/%10 + 1
df
```

results in:

```
    x rank
1   1    1
2   2    1
3   3    1
4   4    1
5   5    1
6   6    1
7   7    1
8   8    1
9   9    1
10 10    1
11 11    2
12 12    2
13 13    2
14 14    2
15 15    2
16 16    2
17 17    2
18 18    2
19 19    2
20 20    2
21 21    3
22 22    3
23 23    3
24 24    3
25 25    3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, This helped what I was trying to achieve. I would keep you suggestion in mind and would work on vectorized calculations

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
subset$Rank <- ceiling(as.numeric(rownames(subset))/10)
```

The as.numeric converts the rowname into a number, dividing it by 10 and rounding up should give you what you need? Let me know if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! What I am trying to achieve is that irrespective of the dataframe length, I want to divide the data frame into 10 groups sequentially based on the rows, and assign each row in a group a rank, such that if I Have a data frame of 24312 rows, the first 2431 rows has rank 1, from row 2432 to 4862 has rank 2, row 4863 to 7293 has rank 3 and so on. I hope that make sense.

Comment: How do you need it split up when the number of rows isn't divisible by 10?